# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "url" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Array

Tags: discord.js

I'm writing a music discord bot using discord.js and ytdl-core, i don't know how to fix this error.

`Error: (node:14720) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "url" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Array`

All code of my bot is here:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
let bot = new Discord.Client()
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core')

bot.on('ready',() => {
    console.log(`bot ${bot.user.username} online!`)
})

bot.on('message', message => {
    const queue = new Map()
    let embedRed = '#ff0000'
    let embedGreen = '#1eff00'
    let messageArray = message.content.split(" ")
    let command = messageArray[0]
    let args = messageArray.slice(1)
    if(command == '!!play') {
        let song = args, voice = message.member.voice.channel
        let connection = voice.join()
        if (!song) {
            message.react("❌")
            let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setAuthor("Error!")
                .addField("Input URL adress of music")
                .setColor(embedRed)
            message.channel.send(embed)
            return
        }
        if (!voice) {
            message.react("❌")
            let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setAuthor("Error!")
                .addField("Join voice channel!")
                .setColor(embedRed)
            message.channel.send(embed)
        }
        let valid = ytdl.validateURL(song)
        if (!valid) {
            message.react("❌")
            let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setAuthor("Error!")
            .addField("Your URL adress is not valid")
            .setColor(embedRed)
        message.channel.send(embed)
        }
        let guild_queue = queue.get(message.guild.id)
        if (!guild_queue) guild_queue = queue.set(message.guild.id, {songs: []}).get(message.guild.id)

        guild_queue.songs.push(song)
        message.react("✅")
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setAuthor("Music")
            .addField("Track added to queue")
            .setColor(embedGreen)
        message.channel.send(embed)
        if (guild_queue.songs.length < 2) play(connection, guild_queue.songs)  
    }
    async function play(connection, songs) {
        const music = ytdl(songs[0], {filter: 'audioonly', quality: 'highestaudio'})
        connection.play(music)
      }
})

bot.login('token')
```

Comment: Added markdown features to improve readability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `messageArray.slice(1)`, it returns an **array**, not a **string**, which is what we want.
Here's what you can do:

- Remove the following lines:

```
    let messageArray = message.content.split(" ")
    let command = messageArray[0]
    let args = messageArray.slice(1)
```

- Split the message into a singular array of arguments. When calling the `split` method, we should use a regular expression instead of a string with a space to match every single occurence so it works even if the user accidentally typed extra spaces between arguments. The arguments array should include the command.

```
let args = message.content.split(/ +/g);
let command = args[0];
```

- The song URL should be the argument in index position 1 provided by the user:

```
let song = args[1];
```

You should no longer be getting a TypeError, because `song` is now a string, which is supposedly the type YTDL was looking for.

**DISCLAIMER:** I have never used YTDL before, so I could be wrong regarding where the error is. If possible, please provide the full stack trace in your question.

Comment: thanks, it's helped me, but i have a new error
connection.play() is not a function again

Comment: That means `connection.play()` is indeed not a method, or `connection` itself is null or undefined. Remember to terminate your statements with semicolons.